# how can I force Google App Script MailApp.sendEmail to use a new thread for each email in a loop?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, automation, gmail-api

I am doing a simple app, I have an spread sheet with a few columns, one is an email addres and the others are filled with the information I want to send in an email to that addres. The code is really simple, it is just a while loop with the execution of `MailApp.sendEmail` with the data in each row.

The issue that I am having is that when I execute the app all the emails end up in the same email threard. And this makes really difficult to follow the responses beacause each email is independet. I've been looking for a while on how to force `MailApp.sendEmail` to start a new thread, but I can't find how to do it in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail) or in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The issue is that you are using the exact same subject for these emails and therefore they end up in the same email thread.

**For example:**

This will put all the emails **in the same** thread:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (let i=0; i<2; i++){
  
  MailApp.sendEmail("example@gmail.com",
                  "Test", // subject is the same for every email
                  "This is an test email");
  }
}
```

This will put the emails in **different** threads:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (let i=0; i<2; i++){
  
  MailApp.sendEmail("example@gmail.com",
                  "Test"+i, // subject is different for every email
                  "This is an test email");
  }
}
```

---

Instead of using `i` which is not very well descriptive as a subject, you could send the datetime:

`"Test"+new Date()`

although this might not work if the emails are sent instantly and therefore the subject will be the same again, but it might work in your case.

Ideally, you would want something that is relevant to the email, for example relevant to the body of your email.

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem! I've included the request number (which is different in every row) and now all the emails are sent in different threads,

Comment: Do you actually get them into a thread with the same subject? I can't get them into a thread no matter what.

Comment: from my tests - it's very unpredictable. sending from GAS to myself doesn't combine them. sending from GAS to other gmail combines. Same email sent one other address and then forwarded combined in one but not the other... Hard to predict and even harder to choose anything except from same or different subject for MailApp..